# Does FaceTime on iOS 14 allow you to share your screen?

Tags: ios, facetime

I know it is possible to do so on macOS, through Messages, but is it possible to do something similar with FaceTime on iOS or iPadOS? Or does one need to use another app for this, like Zoom?

Answer (score 3):

You need another app. To see which apps are available, you can hold the record button in the control center.